# How to validate if Cookie is set in CEF?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to set a cookie

```
CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> manager = CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager(nullptr);
CefCookie cookie;
CefString(&cookie.name).FromString("name");
CefString(&cookie.value).FromString("value");
cookie.httponly = false;
cookie.has_expires = false;
manager->SetCookie(CefString(url),cookie,new CefSetCookie());
```

How do I check whether this cookie is actually set through the headers because when I log the request headers in cef I do not get the cookie I am trying to set.

So what is the right way to check if the cookie has been set without depending on the bool value received after SetCookie is executed.

Comment: "Set-cookie" is a response from the server when it (not your code) wants to set a cookie.  "Cookie" is the client request header listing cookies that have already been set.  To get the current set of cookies CefCookieManager :: VisitUrlCookies() or VisitAllCookies()

Comment: Please stop tagging your question with `CefSharp`. `chromium-embedded` is the correct tag. You aren't using `CefSharp`.